# Combine \clist_use:nn and \clist_map_function:nN with separator

Tags: l3clist

I need to map a list to a function and insert separators between the resulting items.

`\clist_use` accepts a separator but `clist_map_function` doesn't. How can I combine both.

What I've tried:

In the following example `\mybrackets{a, b, c}` outputs `[a][b][c]` and `\mypath{a, b, c}` outputs `a>b>c`.

What I need is the combination of both: `[a]>[b]>[c]`

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mypath { O{>} m } {
    \clist_use:nn { #2 } { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mybrackets { m } {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \myfunction:n
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \myfunction:n #1 {
    [ { #1 } ]
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mybrackets{a, b, c} % outputs [a][b][c]
\mypath{a, b, c}    % outputs a>b>c
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use sequences, that are more flexible than clists.

First you set the “in” sequence, then map it to add the brackets in the “out” sequence, which you can finally use.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \mybrackets { m }
  {
    \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq { #1 }
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_out_seq \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq { [##1] }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_out_seq { > }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mybrackets{a, b, c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use an indexed mapping:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \mybrackets { m }
  {
    \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq { #1 }
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq \__wolfrevo_mybrackets_do:nn
  }

\cs_new:Nn \__wolfrevo_mybrackets_do:nn
  {
    \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1 } { > } [#2]
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mybrackets{a, b, c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \@egreg Thanks. Two questions:
1) Is there any difference between `\seq_indexed_map_function` and `\seq_map_indexed_function`?
2) Is it necessary to declare `\seq_new:N \l__wolfrevo_mybrackets_in_seq` outside `\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n`? It is not used elsewhere.

Comment: @wolfrevo Sorry, I always get the name wrong! Any used variable should be declared.

Comment: \@egreg. Is it necessary to declared it inside `\cs_new_protected:Nn \wolfrevo_mybrackets:n` instead of outside it?

Comment: @wolfrevo Why should it be inside? Generally speaking, variables should be declared at the top level, not inside functions that use them. Exception for variables dynamically generated, but it's not this case.

Comment: \@egreg: Sorry. I was just asking. Coming from other programming languages I get used to declare variables only within the scope they will be used. E.g. to prevent that other functions mess up with the variable.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can add an empty separator before the first item

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N\l_mypath_sep


\NewDocumentCommand \mybrackets { m } {
        \tl_set:Nn\l_mypath_sep{}
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \myfunction:n
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \myfunction:n #1 {
     \l_mypath_sep
    \tl_set:Nn\l_mypath_sep{~>~}
    [ { #1 } ]
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mybrackets{a, b, c} % outputs [a] > [b] > [c]

\end{document}
```

Comment: \@DavidCarlisle: Very nice trick! But, what if different commands call `\myfunction`? The state of `\l_mypath_sep` might be unpredictable.

Comment: @wolfrevo well you document that you need to initialise the state and if you call it without following the documentation, that's user error.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, what we can do at TeX primitive level:

```
\def\mybrackets#1{\mybracketsA#1,\end}
\def\mybracketsA#1,#2{\ifx\end#2[#1]\else [#1]>\expandafter\mybracketsA\expandafter#2\fi}

\mybrackets{a, b, c}  % prints [a]<[b]<[c]
```

Comment: But, of course, this wouldn't remove all spaces around commas. Only those *after*.